# JMenuItem Java creación

Tags: java, jmenubar

Necesito una aplicación que me cree x menús dependiendo del valor de una variable.

[image: En el segundo submenú se deben crear menús dependiendo del valor de una variable]

Es decir, que en la parte del menú de la derecha si la variable que tengo vale 3, pues que se creen 3 menús, sin vale 5, pues 5 y así.

He encontrado más o menos la forma de hacerlo, pero necesito corregir algo que no sé cómo corregir. Os dejo el código para ver si me podéis ayudar.

```
for (int i = 0; i< idiomas.size(); i++)
    {
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(idiomas.get(i));
    item.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            _chosenLang = i;

            hideEverything();

            initComponents();
        }
    });
    _newconfigb.add(item);
    }
```

El problema está en que ahora a _chosenLang no le puedo asignar i porque no es final y necesito poder asignarle i ya que dependiendo de esa i, el programa tomará unas opciones u otras. El error que lanza es

> local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es lo que te indica el mensaje; estás declarando una clase local anónima

```
 new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
   ...
 }
```

y dentro de uno de sus métodos haces referencia a una variable `i` declarada en el método "padre".

Esto se denomina *closure*, y lo que haría en otros lenguajes sería que, al ejecutar `actionPerformed`, *cogería el valor de la variable i*. Así por ejemplo (JavaScript)

```
var funcion;

{
   var i = 5;
   funcion = new function() {
   alert("Hola mundo " + i);
   i = 42;
}
funcion();
```

mostraría "Hola mundo 42"; JS se encarga de mantener "viva" la variable `i`

Pero en Java, `i` deja de existir tan pronto salga del bloque donde está definido, así que hace un "truco" y te deja acceder al valor, pero lo único que hace es copiarlo. Pero, para evitar que la gente intente hacer lo mismo que en JavaScript, obliga a que:

- la variable esté marcada como `final` (no modificable), o
- a partir de Java 8, aunque la variable no esté marcada como final, debe actuar como tal (no se debe modificar).

Así pues

```
{
  final int i = 5;
  item.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    });
}
```

### BIEN

```
{
  int i = 5;
  item.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    });
}
```

### BIEN <sup>en Java 8 y siguientes</sup>

```
{
  int i = 5;
  item.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    });
  i++;
}
```

### MAL

Además, por tu código, parece que no quieres usar `i` como closure, sino sólamente usarlo como "estado" del `listener`. La solución para eso es hacer una clase no anónima (que puede ser local), de forma que puedas pasar el valor por constructor, método)

```
 class MiListener implements ActionListener {
   private int _lang;
   public MiListener(int lang) {
     this._lang = lang;
   }

   // actionPerformed y demás.
 };

for (int i = 0; i< idiomas.size(); i++)
{
  JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(idiomas.get(i));
  item.addActionListener(new MiListener(i));
}
```